# If there a way to know the IP address of a machine when I use "\\" to access to?

Tags: windows, network-share

I normally access to an organisation shared folder by typing `\\someserver` in Windows `run` command, Is there any method to know the IP address of the server that I am accessing to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Name resolution in recent Windows systems is done via DNS protocol. Old versions were using WINS and NBNS.
The tool to resolve a name using DNS is `nslookup`.
For WINS you can use `nblookup`

Comment: Can a simple ping the server name work?

Comment: I do not think that `ping` will use other resolving mechanisms besides `hosts` file  and DNS.